# Are there any advanced payroll type services with an API that allow a server to add contractors and pay them on the fly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment, stripe-payments

We are building a service/iPhone app that functions similar to Uber. Is there any payroll service that allows a developer to automate the process of adding users who sign up as an employee/contractor of the service? The closest thing I've found is [Zen Payroll](http://zenpayroll.com). The second, very important part, is payment. After the employee renders his/her services to a consumer, the consumer will pay the app (we will use Stripe as the payment service), and the app will forward 80% of the payment directly to the employee.

In the Uber analogy: The driver signs up to drive for Uber. They get added to the payroll service and the Uber server as an employee/independent contractor. A consumer request a ride, gets a ride from the driver, and is charged 20 bucks. The consumer pays Uber 20 bucks, and 18 bucks get sent directly to the employee right away.

Is this possible with any existing service? Does anyone know Uber's pay schedule? ZenPayroll has an API to allow adding employees and what not but I assume you still only pay on scheduled pay periods like a typical payroll (every other week or once a month). Additional note, the webserver will be built using Ruby on Rails, so services with good support on RoR get huge bonus points.

Comment: What country? Stripe US allows transfers to bank accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking into this too. Besides ZenPayroll, these two also look promising:

- [Payable](http://www.payable.com)
- [Bold](https://gobold.com)